# Get subtract weekday

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008, in this I can get weekday of today as

```
select datepart(weekday, GETDATE()) WeekDay
```

and it will be returning `5` as weekday. I need to subtract `1` from this, i.e. 5-1 = 4.

Here's what I've tried:

```
select dateadd(weekday, -1, datepart(weekday, GETDATE())) WeekDay
```

but it is returning `1900-01-05 00:00:00.000`

Why am I not getting 4 and why is it showing this date? Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you are really trying to do, instead of saying you want to subtract a weekday. As written your query makes no sense, you are using DATEPART(WEEKDAY which returns an INT, not a DATE, then you are trying to subtract a WEEKDAY (instead of a DAY) from an INT. Please explain your actual goal instead of how you think you should accomplish it...

Comment: I tried to get current weekday-1. its working, I just wanted to know y it was returning that date. I got it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will surely returns 4.

```
select  datepart(weekday,GETDATE())-1 WeekDay
```

Comment: And you want 0 when today's weekday = 1? That's no longer a valid weekday.

Comment: then Y it returns the date as `1900-01-05 00:00:00.000` when I use dateadd

Comment: Because DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) returns an integer. 5 is 5 days after SQL Server's "zero date", 1900-01-01. So that +5 = 1900-01-06, then you subtract a day, 1900-01-05. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I tried to get current weekday-1. its working, I just wanted to know y it was returning that date, thats all. thanks Aaron for ur response

Comment: Because WEEKDAY (e.g. 5) is an INT, not a DATE. When you mistakenly treat it as a date, SQL Server thinks you mean a numerical date, as in "zero date" (1900-01-01) + 5.

Comment: oh 1900-01-01 is `Zero date`?, cool. I learnt something new today coz of u , thanks again Aaron

Comment: Yes, try `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Is this you looking for

```
SELECT DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) AS WeekDay;
```